# Source file inclusion in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I've just Installed visual studio express 2015 on my PC and when I try to add a new source file to a project by right clicking on the 'source files' option in the solution explorer , the dialog box shows "no items found" instead of showing installed visual C++ templates. What could the problem be?

Comment: Run `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /installvstemplates` and check if it installed any C++ templates

Answer (score 0):

You most probably have not installed VC++ has while installing Visual Studio. It is sad that C++ is now not installed by **default**. You might have selected "Default" while installing VS - you should have chosen **Custom** and selected Visual C++ development. You need to re-install it (just re-launch setup).

If this doesn't help, please post the screenshot.

Comment: Running the setup again and pressing 'repair' doesn't change anything. I'll have to try uninstall and reinstall.